# Make the degree symbol on the top of letter

Tags: microsoft-word, equations

I want to type

[image: e̊_d]

in the equation on Microsoft Word. I cannot make the "degree" symbol on the top of letter "e". How to make it?

I have tried to type it

[image: e_d^o]

and I give up.

Comment: For some diacritical marks, e.g.,  U+212B Å, the easiest way to type them is to add an International Keyboard. You can also look up the character in Character Map - and it might only be available in s specific font. Finally, when you've found the Unicode character value, hold the Alt key and type the decimal value using the *number* keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to Insert -> Symbols, Click on Equations.
2. On the equation editor, type: `e\above("°")`, then press Enter.

Note that after entering `(`, the writing will be turned to `e┴(`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a math equation then type `eU+030A` then press  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

[image: eU+030A Alt+X]